# How to use C++20 in OS X 10.8?

Tags: macos, qt, clang, osx-mountain-lion, macports

I have a very old mac with Mac OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion installed. Unfortunately, upgrade is not an option. I really need to use C++ 20 standart in my QT 5.7.1 for my university projects.

I tried to follow [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t0WO9ULnl4w) guide, but it didn't help. Also tried, using the same logic, install new clang. Also didn't work. Can anybody please help? Really need to use modern C++ on this system

Photos:

> [C++ version test .pro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fP08v.png),  [C++ version test .cpp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnKsu.png), [clang installed succesfully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7ADq.png)

[Qt Kits](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNUUd.png)
[Qt Compilers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1OfT.png)

Comment: That video is awful for suggesting you should replace your system toolchain. Never do that.

Comment: @nostromo Homebrew doesn't work on this old system. As I understand, MacPorts is the same as Homebrew, but for old systems

Comment: You may have better luck with old platform support with [Macports](https://www.macports.org/install.php#installing) rather than Homebrew.

Comment: @Eljay, yeah, I tried MacPorts folowwing the guide. It didn't work :(

Comment: I would first try .... sudo port install gcc8 ... or gcc9 ... and then try to compile with it.

Comment: I'd say installing a VM with Linux might be a better option for you.